# rewritecond with query string works, but when i submit a new query from the clean url, it just appends the url with the old query string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

Here is are my rewrite rules and conditions

```
#link ReWrite
RewriteRule ^searchresults/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /searchresults.php?search=1&year_search_type=single&isused=$1&year=$2&make=$3&model=$4&price=$5 [L]

#query Rewrite
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/searchresults.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*[&]?isused=(\w+).*&year=(\w+).*&make=(\w+).*&model=(\w+).*&price=(\w+).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /searchresults/%1/%2/%3/%4/%5? [R=301,L]
```

Situation - 
i have a search page that searches the database and shows results. This setup catches the Query and rewrites it to clean urls (awesome!) BUT if i run a query a second time, aka from the cleaned url, the search request now just adds the original ?key=value&key=value to the clean url to make the request.

searchresults.php?make=value&model=value turns into searchresults/value/value as i want it to

but when i run the second query from searchresults/value/value  it ends up turning it into
        /searchresults/value/value?make=value&model=value

any way to defeat that from within .htaccess as the search query itself is in some deep php crazy land of code, and i honestly cant even find the thing, so editing the php is not in the cards.

ALSO, as a bonus, if anyone can tell me what edits to make so that when the query sends a request that looks like   key=value+with+spaces  i get the correct clean url back? right now it takes  key=value+with+spaces and gives me back "value" but drops off with+spaces and moves onto the next key value pair....

THANKS

Comment: for the first part can i add a "search for cleaned urls and when you do a query with that as your requestURL clean that up by removing the cleaned stuff first? or soemthing

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're having the problem, your rules worked perfectly fine for me on a vanilla apache install in a blank htaccess file. But you can try changing your rules a little:

The first thing you need to do is swap the order of your two rules. The redirect rule **must be before** any internal rewrites. This prevents two rules from being applied to the same request (the rewrite engine loops through all the rules until the URI stops changing). Second, you need to match against the actual request instead of the `%{QUERY_STRING}` match against the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+searchresults\.php\?.*[&]?isused=(\w+).*&year=(\w+).*&make=(\w+).*&model=(\w+).*&price=(\w+).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /searchresults/%1/%2/%3/%4/%5? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^searchresults/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /searchresults.php?search=1&year_search_type=single&isused=$1&year=$2&make=$3&model=$4&price=$5 [L]
```

Comment: yeah the rule works fine, but i think the issue is after the rewrite, the new url isnt seen as a requestURL anymore so it doesnt catch the query and apply the rule it just lets the query try to run itself with the rewritten url as if it was results.php to begin with...

Comment: works the same, as original. also to note that when i go to use the drop down it tries like a quick refresh and then i see like 3 search box pages on top of each other lol... im so confused on how that even happens from a rewrite.

Comment: yeah it looks like the script is setup for a live refresh if you change a dropdown... and i just noticed that i probably should not have tried this with the 301 redirect until i knew it was working because now when i remove all the reewrites... its still looking for the redirected url...:(